# Pointer to adress seems to be adjusted out of scope

Tags: c++, pointers

We are currently building some tree, called a BVH. To build it, we have a large pool containing the maximum number of nodes that could be present. 
While building the root node of the tree, we point to the address in the pool that contains the corresponding node information.

Therefore we have:

```
class BVHNode
{
  int leftFirst;
  //some stuff
}

class BVH
{
   vector<BVHNode> pool;
   BVHNode* root;
   //some more stuff
}

BVH::ConstructBVH()
{
  // some stuff
  (*this).pool.resize(maxNodesNr);
  (*this).root = &pool[0];
  (*this).root->leftFirst = 0;
 //more stuff
}
```

Then we have a method SetGeometry, where the bvh construction gets called, and the resulting bvh is saved to the scene.

```
RenderCore::SetGeometry()
{
   Timer timer; //nothing important

   Mesh newMesh = Mesh();

   //some stuff to copy vertices to newMesh

   newMesh.bvh.ConstructBVH();
   raytracer.scene.meshList.push_back(newMesh);
   printf("newMesh contains correct root!");
}
```

Now if we place a breakpoint at the printf, the bvh.root shows the correct leftFirst.
If we place another breakpoint at Timer timer, the next time we get to that breakpoint, the root->leftFirst shows -572662307. Which I think indicates it points at a random memory location.
The pool[0] itself, still shows the correct info.
Between the SetGeometry calls, nothing alters anything within the bvh. 
I think it might be that something has undefined behavior when it goes out of the SetGeometry scope, but I cannot determine what and why exactly, since only the root seems to be altered, and the rest within the bvh still seems to be valid. If you have any suggestions, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Isn't `(*this).root = &pool[0];` wrong if you didn't insert anything in vector `pool`? So, `(*this).root->leftFirst = 0;` is undefined behavior

Comment: oh sorry, i didnt mention. I called pool.resize( maxNr of nodes). I will adjust my question

Comment: A semi-educated guess: `raytracer.scene.meshList.push_back(newMesh);` creates a copy of `newMesh` and your `BVH` class does not have a copy constructor (violating the Rule of Three), meaning your `root` pointer points to an old vector that has been deleted

Comment: @kuro, yes I access it via the `raytracer.scene.meshlist`. I thought the copy would do that correctly, but as @UnholySheep mentioned, I think it might be a copy problem. I did not know of the existance of a copy constructor. I will look into that.

Comment: Unrelated: Why `(*this).root = ...` instead of `this->root = ...` or just  `root = ...`?

Comment: @Ted, I have ```root =``` in my code, it was just to be clear it was tied to the class, but apparently it works out the opposite and is not clear to you.

Comment: @AmberElferink Oh, it was clear alright. It's just uncommon to access non-operator member functions that way. `this->root = ...` would be the more common and easily parsed by humans if you want clarity. Btw, shouldn't `pool` also have `this->` infront of it to not give the impression that it's not owned by `this`?

Comment: @UnholySheep, if you like, please post your solution as an answer. And I will accept it. We are rewriting it to omit copying the entire mesh, since that does not seem a great thing to do anyway.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, Thanks for the tip. I always just wrote ```(*this).```. At least now I know there is another way.

Comment: @AmberElferink There's absoluetely nothing wrong with `(*this)` but be consistent. You should make it `(*this).pool.resize(maxNodesNr);` too in that case.

Comment: Why do you even have a data member `root` ? Seems you could have `BVHNode* root() { return &pool[0]; }` and that would work even if the pool would grow. `std::vector` **does** have a correct copy ctor, and you don't need to define a copy ctor when all your members have an appropriate copy constructor.

Comment: @MSalters, is there any reason why not to have data member root? There will be limited amount of BVHes, so I'm not really worried about memory use.

Comment: @AmberElferink: The point is that it's unnecessary and forces you to have a copy constructor. (And probably an assignment operator too). So no upsides , only downsides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `raytracer.scene.meshList.push_back(newMesh);` pushes a *copy* of `newMesh` into the `meshList`.
Since `BVH` does not have a user-defined copy constructor the default copy constructor assigns `root` to point to the same `pool` as the original.
As the original `BVH` in `newMesh` gets destroyed when the `SetGeometry` function is exited, the remaining `root` pointer becomes dangling.